# How to create Query using IN?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I need to collect data and add it to temporary table in **AX 2012 R3** using **X++**.

This is the Query on SQL

```
select store, receiptid, itemid, str(qty,16,0) as Qty, str(price,16,0) as   Price, str(DISCAMOUNT,16,0) DiscAmount, str(taxamount,16,0) SalesTaxAmount ,convert(date, transdate) transdate, DATAAREAID from RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS
where DATAAREAID in ('5740','5760') and transdate >='2016-03-21' and transdate <='2016-03-27' and store in ('JTJDRN1','JNUSADP','JOFFICE')
and INVENTSTATUSSALES='2' and itemid in ('10010038') and receiptid in (select receiptid from RETAILTRANSACTIONPAYMENTTRANS where transdate >='2016-03-21' and transdate <='2016-03-27')
order by transdate
```

User can input transDate, itemid and storeid

this is what form looks like [image]

this is my code so far

```
private void RetailPromoReport()
{
str         receiptId, curDatetxt,fileLocation, filePath, itemtxt,  startPtxt, endPtxt,
            storetxt, item_txt, item2, receiptId2, rcptid_txt, store_txt, store2;
FileName    fileName;
str 50      item, itemid, store;
container   items, receiptid_con, stores;
int         i,x, ware, itm, tot, y,z, rcptLen, storeLen;

Date        emptyDate, startP, endP;

RetailTransactionPaymentTrans   rtpt;
RetailTransactionSalesTrans     rtst;
ReportRetailTemp                rrpi_tmp, rrpi_tmp2;

QueryBuildRange         qbr1, qbr2, qbr3, qbr4, qbr5;

QueryRun                queryRun;
Query                   query, query2;
QueryBuildDataSource    qbdsRetailTransactionPaymentTrans, qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans;

RecordInsertList       recordILCRppi_tmp = new RecordInsertList(tableNum(ReportRetailTemp),false,false,false,false,false,rrpi_tmp);
;

startP   = DateFrom.dateValue();
endP     = DateTo.dateValue();
tot      = 0;

delete_from rrpi_tmp;

while  select receiptId from rtpt group by rtpt.receiptId where rtpt.transDate >= startP && rtpt.transDate <= endP
{
    receiptid_con += rtpt.receiptId;
}

query = new Query();

qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans = query.addDataSource(tableNum(RetailTransactionSalesTrans));
qbr1 = qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addRange(fieldNum(RetailTransactionSalesTrans,TransDate));
qbr1.value(strfmt('(%3.transDate>=%1) && (%3.transDate<=%2)',Date2StrXpp(startP),Date2StrXpp(endP),qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.name()));

qbr2 = qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addRange(fieldNum(RetailTransactionSalesTrans,inventStatusSales));
qbr2.value(queryValue(enum2str(RetailInventStatusSales::Posted)));

items = msCtrlCust.getSelectedFieldValues();
itemtxt = multilookupItem.valueStr();

stores = msCtrlStore.getSelectedFieldValues();
storetxt = multilookupStore.valueStr();

if(itemtxt != "")
{
    item_txt = conPeek(items,1);
    item2 = strFmt('(%2.itemId == "%1") ',queryValue(conPeek(items,1)),qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.name());

    itm = conlen(items);
    if(itm > 1)
    {
         for (i = 2; i <= itm;i++)
         {
             item = conPeek(items,i);
             item2 = strFmt('%1 || (%3.itemId == "%2") ',item2, queryValue(item),qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.name());
         }
    }

    qbr3 = qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addRange(fieldNum(RetailTransactionSalesTrans, itemId));
    qbr3.value(strFmt("%1",item2));
}

rcptLen = conlen(receiptid_con);
receiptId2 = strFmt('(%2.receiptId == "%1") ',queryValue(conPeek(receiptid_con,1)),qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.name());

if(rcptLen > 1)
{
    for (y = 2; y <= rcptLen; y++)
    {
        rcptid_txt = conPeek(receiptid_con,y);
        receiptId2 = strFmt('%1 || (%3.receiptId == "%2") ',receiptId2, queryValue(rcptid_txt),qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.name());
     }
}

qbr4 = qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addRange(fieldNum(RetailTransactionSalesTrans, receiptId));
qbr4.value(strFmt("%1",receiptId2));

if(storetxt != '')
{
    store_txt = conPeek(stores,1);
    store2 = strFmt('(%2.store == "%1") ',queryValue(conPeek(stores,1)),qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.name());

    storeLen = conlen(stores);
    if(storeLen > 1)
    {
         for (z = 2; z <= storeLen;z++)
         {
             store = conPeek(stores,z);
             store2 = strFmt('%1 || (%3.store == "%2") ',store2, queryValue(store),qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.name());
         }
    }

    qbr5 = qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addRange(fieldNum(RetailTransactionSalesTrans, store));
    qbr5.value(strFmt("%1",store2));
}


qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addSortField(fieldNum(RetailTransactionSalesTrans, transDate),SortOrder::Ascending);
qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addSortField(fieldNum(RetailTransactionSalesTrans, itemId),SortOrder::Ascending);

queryRun = new QueryRun(query);

while (queryRun.next())
{
    rtst                    = queryRun.getNo(1);

    rrpi_tmp.store          = rtst.store;
    rrpi_tmp.receiptId      = rtst.receiptId;
    rrpi_tmp.itemId         = rtst.itemId;
    rrpi_tmp.qty            = rtst.qty;
    rrpi_tmp.price          = rtst.price;
    rrpi_tmp.discAmount     = rtst.discAmount;
    rrpi_tmp.SalestaxAmount = rtst.taxAmount;
    rrpi_tmp.transDate      = rtst.transDate;

    recordILCRppi_tmp.add(rrpi_tmp);
    tot++;
}

 ttsBegin;
    recordILCRppi_tmp.insertDatabase();
 ttsCommit;

    ReportRetailTemp_ds.research(true);
    ReportRetailTemp_ds.refresh();

    if(tot > 0)
    {
        Box::info(strFmt("%1 row data",tot));
    }
    else
    {
        Box::info(strFmt("No Data",tot));
    }
}
```

My code doesn't show any error in short period but because receiptId is stored in str,

```
receiptId2 = strFmt('%1 || (%3.receiptId == "%2") ',receiptId2, queryValue(rcptid_txt),qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.name());
```

there is limitation and show error for long periode

Can someone make my code more efficient and 
is there any way to create Query in x++ that have same function like "IN" on SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

- You can use more than one query range for the same field; it will automatically count as an `or`

  ```
  for (i = conLen(items); i > 0; i--)
      qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addRange(fieldNum(RetailTransactionSalesTrans, itemId)).value(queryValue(conPeek(items,i)));
  ```

  You may need special handling, if the container is empty!
- Often it is better to use an (exists) join instead

  ```
  ds = qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addDatasource(tableNum(RetailTransactionPaymentTrans));
  ds.joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);
  ds.relations(true); // Or do ds.addLink(...) etc.
  ```

  I am not sure I follow the correct logic here :)

If you need to do crosscompany selections, do so using the interface for that:

```
qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.allowCrossCompany(true);
qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addCompanyRange('5740');
qbdsRetailTransactionSalesTrans.addCompanyRange('5760');
```